# Why is base class enum not inherited?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, inheritance, enums

So I have the following arrangement using Visual Studio 2008:

```
class Base {
protected:
  int data_;
protected:
  enum {special_sauce = 1234};
};

class Derived : public Base {
  friend class DataAccessor;
};

class DataAccessor {
public:
  int AccessData(Derived* object){
    return object->data_;
  }
  bool CheckData(Derived* object){
    return object->data_ == Derived::special_sauce;
  }
};
```

Everything functions well. Now, making this change (Making Base and Derived *(edit: replaced "subclasses")* inner classes of DataAccessor) ...

```
class DataAccessor {
public:
  class Base {
  protected:
    int data_;
  protected:
    enum {special_sauce = 1234};
  };

  class Derived : public Base {
    friend class DataAccessor;
  };

public:
  int AccessData(Derived* object){
    return object->data_;
  }
  bool CheckData(Derived* object){
    return object->data_ == Derived::special_sauce;
  }
};
```

I get the following errors:

```
error C2248: 'special_sauce' : cannot access protected enumerator declared in class 'DataAccessor::Base'
see declaration of 'special_sauce'
see declaration of 'DataAccessor::Base'
```

Why is this happening, and why isn't the member `data_` affected the same way?

Comment: Because friendship is not [inherited, transitive, or reciprocal](https://svn.ali.global/GDK_games/GDK_games/BigFortune/tags/gampro_usa_1.01_61944.008/source/).

Comment: "Making Base and Derived subclasses of DataAccessor" they are not subclasses, but inner class

Comment: So I ran the second code at http://www.compileonline.com/ and it works fine. I assume it's a bug in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious 1. If that's the rule that applies here, then why isn't `data_` protected from DataAccessor::AccessData? 2. Why then, is the first snippet compiling fine?

Comment: Ran this at https://ideone.com/, also works fine. Ran it in Visual Studio 2012 - same problem as in 2008. http://codepad.org/ also approves.

Comment: Tested this using MinGW, cc.exe and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds similar to [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/676979/vs2010-compiler-bug) for the VS compiler. More discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af254a22-3ca8-4e64-b416-09410bb2bab6/vs2008-compiler-bug?forum=vclanguage).

```
class BaseClass{
public :
  friend class FriendOfBaseClass;

protected :
  static void f() {};
  class InnerBaseClass {}; 
  enum TheType { state_0=0 };
};

class FriendOfBaseClass {};


class Class2 {
public :

  class InnerClassOfClass2 : public BaseClass {
  public :
    friend class FrienOfInnerClass;
  };
};


class FrienOfInnerClass : public FriendOfBaseClass {
public :
  void TheProblemIsHere()
  {    
    Class2::InnerClassOfClass2::f();                        // This compiles well
    Class2::InnerClassOfClass2::InnerBaseClass y;  // This compiles well
    int x=Class2::InnerClassOfClass2::state_0;       // Compilation error here!
  }
};
```

> error C2248: 'state_0' : cannot access protected enumerator declared in class 'BaseClass'